# top part of large div at bottom is not shown in android-browsers

Tags: android, html, css

this is a simple html + css question:

My 620px tall div with bottom: 0px is not scrollable in android-browsers - it hangs on the bottom, the top is missing and not reachable. Tested with Android 4.4.2 on my tablet (1280x800) in Firefox, Crome an "Internet"-Browser.

[browser photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8rNi.jpg)

This is what I want:
* the div at bottom on large not mobile screens
* the whole content scrollable on mobile screens

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }
  html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

<body bgcolor="white" text="white">
 <div style="
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  height: 620px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -450px;
  bottom: 0px; 
  background-color: green;
  ">
  a tall container
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help and attention..

Comment: Recommend you use 'media queries'.

Comment: Because, you have given bottom:0;, hence it will stick to bottom. try to use @media queries for smaller devices

Comment: Ok, so I have to learn this... I guess you are right and there is no other simple way. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Try, giving `position:relative;` to the  parent div or body in your above code.

Comment: I tried without success. With `position:relative;` the bottom-position is lost on tall screens. This works only with `absolute` or `fixed position` in the div. I tried all variations with these positions in body and div. If you like to check the page on your mobile: [link](http://www.jahnna.de/test3.html).